# when trying to run dag and Airflow returning status code2

Tags: python, airflow

Hey I am really stuggling here with airflow on this. I have two other dags running no probllem however for some reasons these dags are failing and I'm not getting much back that makes sense to me in the logs. I can run this task with no issues as the airflow user through the command line but for some reason when I try doing it through the dag I get exit code 2. Has anyone some pointers on this? Thank you

> [2018-09-18 20:08:18,886] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: run pull_dcm_today_data pull_dcm_today_data 2018-09-18T19:00:00 --job_id 8 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/run_pull_dcm_today.py
>
> [2018-09-18 20:08:22,579] {jobs.py:2083} INFO - Task exited with return code 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try testing each one of the tasks in order using the `airflow test` command. If all the tasks run successfully but the DAG's keep failing you probably need to restart the whole project (webserver, scheduler and workers) because you might have outdated code somewhere.